# All jobs in Q queue for Torque Pbs scheduler

Tags: debian, cluster-computing, pbs, torque

I am new with torque/pbs scheduler, and I installed it in server on one debian 8 machine and make another installation in client on a compute node with debian 8 too.

On my server I have pbs_server and pbs_sched running, on my compute node there is pbs_mom, every logs has no errors in it, pbsnode -a seems good :

```
root@debian8s-1:[torque]>pbsnodes -a
debian8s-2
     state = free
     power_state = Running
     np = 4
     ntype = cluster
     status = rectime=1458048686,macaddr=00:14:5d:0f:8d:08,cpuclock=Fixed,varattr=,jobs=,state=free,netload=109918452,gres=,loadave=0.32,ncpus=4,physmem=16432364kb,availmem=20066372kb,totmem=20337896kb,idletime=13385,nusers=1,nsessions=3,sessions=989 992 998,uname=Linux debian8s-2 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4 (2015-09-19) x86_64,opsys=linux
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003
```

and every jobs I submit is stuck in Q :

```
root@debian8s-1:[torque]>qstat
Job ID                    Name             User            Time Use S Queue
------------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
3.debian8s-1               STDIN            tototo                 0 Q batch          
5.debian8s-1               my_job           tototo                 0 Q batch          
6.debian8s-1               STDIN            tototo                 0 Q batch          
7.debian8s-1               STDIN            tototo                 0 Q batch          
8.debian8s-1               STDIN            tototo                 0 Q batch
```

I looked for documentation but didn't find anything about this problem, does anybody has an idea of what I missed?

thanks.

Comment: First check the scheduler logs. You could use `tracejob 3` or `qstat -f 3` to get information on the job #3. Print the server and queue configuration using `qmgr -c print server`. Post your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Per Dmitri's comment, `tracejob` and are `qstat -f` are good places to look. Of course, you'll want to verify that `pbs_sched` is actually running; if that is the case, then you will want to troubleshoot by checking the `pbs_mom` logs, which you'll find, by default, in `/var/spool/torque/mom_logs/<YYYYMMDD>` on the compute nodes (if in doubt, run `pbs_mom --about` for install details. Also, especially in cases where jobs fail to start, you may have to look for `pbs_mom` log entries in `/var/log/messages` on the MOM host. You can submit a test job to run on a specific node like this:

`echo sleep 600 | qsub -l nodes=cn001:ppn=1,walltime=630`

Then, you can force it to run by issuing `qrun <job ID>`

Also, you can issue `kill -SIGUSR1 $(pgrep pbs_mom)` on the node to increase the logging (or `momctl -q loglevel` to see the current level, and `momctl -q loglevel=6` to alter it).